# Run exe file in Java code on Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, exe, azure-hdinsight

I'm trying to run exe from my Java code on Hadoop (HDInsight implementation). I have no sources of exe file, so I must run it like it is. On input of exe must be file, so I can't use streaming. I was trying to use ShellCommandExecutor, but it failed.

```
String[] command = new String[] { "C:/pepnovo3/PepNovo",
                    "-file", "smallinputfile.mgf", "-model", "CID_IT_TRYP" };
ShellCommandExecutor shell = new ShellCommandExecutor(command);
shell.execute();
```

That gives me exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:/pepnovo3/PepNovo": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
```

I was also trying to use ProcessBuilder, and it also failed (same reason). I was trying to do this from HDFS also, and also failed.
I know, that Hadoop isn't perefect platform to do this, but that is my task. It is even possible to do it?

Comment: Did you make sure that `C:/pepnovo3/PepNovo` actually exists?

Comment: Yes, the file exists in this location.

Comment: Are you sure it does not have an extension, like `.exe`? Extensions can be hidden in windows explorer

Comment: Yes, there is extension, but C:/pepnovo3/PepNovo.exe doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

Three possibilities looking at this:

- Is the executable on all of the nodes?
- Is the file being referenced (smallinputfile.mgf) in the working directory of the job (eg, placed with the -files parameter)?
- Does the Hadoop user for the jobs have security permissions on the folder and the file in order to execute it?

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: I have one node in my cluster, so yes, executable is on all of nodes. The smallinputfile.mgf is in the same folder with executable (C:\pepnovo3\). What is Hadoop user on HDInsight? I have 3 groups of users (SYSTEM, Administrators, Users) and each one has full permissions to folder C:\pepnovo3\.